# Shell Script: how to read a text file that does not end with a newline on Windows

Tags: bash, shell

The following program reads a file and it intends to store the all values (each line) into a variable but doesn't store the last line. Why?

*file.txt* :

```
   1
   2
   .
   .
   .
   n
```

*Code* :

```
 FileName=file.txt

if test -f $FileName         # Check if the file exists
    then
        while read -r line
        do    
            fileNamesListStr="$fileNamesListStr $line"

        done < $FileName
    fi

  echo "$fileNamesListStr"  // 1 2 3 ..... n-1 (but it should print up to n.)
```

Comment: Does your file end with a newline?

Comment: @jackrabbit: no. actually most of the client doesn't know and they write the file without ending with new line. therefore i'm looking for such solution which should work in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading line-by-line, why not read the whole file at once?

```
[ -f $FileName ] && fileNameListStr=$( tr '\n' ' ' < $FileName )
```

Comment: simply superb & very efficient :) +100

Comment: also i wanted to give a notification if file is missing??

Comment: @user1010399, then use an `if` statement with an `else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

One probable cause is that there misses a newline after the last line `n`.

Use the following command to check it:

```
tail -1 file.txt
```

And the following fixes:

```
echo >> file.txt
```

If you really need to keep the last line **without** newline, I reorganized the `while` loop here.

```
#!/bin/bash
FileName=0
if test -f $FileName ; then
    while [ 1 ] ; do    
        read -r line
        if [ -z $line ] ; then
            break
        fi
        fileNamesListStr="$fileNamesListStr $line"
    done < $FileName
fi
echo "$fileNamesListStr"
```

Comment: thanks for your time. if i use `tail -1 file.txt` then it returns the last line (`n`) either file ends with a new line or not, `echo >> file.txt` adds a new blank line at the end whether file ends with new line or not. so i don't think it's much useful in my case

Comment: i want to check first, if file ends with a new line `do nothing`. else `echo >> file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when the file does not end in a newline, read returns non-zero and the loop does not proceed. The read command will still read the data, but it will not process the loop. This means that you need to do further processing outside of the loop. You also probably want an array instead of a space separated string.

FileName=file.txt

```
if test -f $FileName         # Check if the file exists
    then
        while read -r line
        do    
            fileNamesListArr+=("$line")

        done < $FileName

        [[ -n $line ]] && fileNamesListArr+=("$line")
fi

echo "${fileNameListArr[@]}"
```

See the "My text files are broken! They lack their final newlines!" section of this article:
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Thanks jordanm. it's working in both case either the file ends with new line or not. many thanks for your time & the solution you provided.

Comment: which one is efficient `space separated string Vs Array string` in terms of memory space &  accessing the stored data.

Comment: @user1010399 The benefit of my solution is that it can handle filenames in the file containing spaces, whereas the others can not. I am not sure on the RAM difference, but it is very likely negligible. If you are wanting to squeeze out a little less memory usage and speed, then you are using the wrong language.

Comment: +100 ! Thanks jordanm. basically i am a java  programmer and don't have much idea about shell script. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, before reading from the text file a newline can be appended to the file.

```
echo "\n" >> $file_path
```

This will ensure that all the lines that was previously in the file will be read. Now the file can be read line by line.